# tar "--exclude-from" double star wildcard

Tags: tar, wildcards

I wrote a backup script on my Debian 8 system which uses tar command with "--exclude-from" to exclude some files/dir.

This works great, but today I would like to exclude some files sharing the same path pattern, like `/home/www-data/sites/<some_string>log.txt` or directories like `/home/www-data/sites/<one_or_two_directories>/vendor`.

I tried to append `/home/www-data/sites/*log.txt` into the file, but tar fails and outputs on stderr the following errors:

```
tar: /home/www-data/sites/*log.txt: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Did I miss something when trying to use `*` or `**` ?

I then read that *in Unix, programs usually do not interpret wildcards themselves* which means that `*` isn't expanded neither `**` by tar.

As far as I know, my last resort here is to expand the list using bash and append it into the exclusion file (if it's not already there) prior to the `tar` call. Is there a cleaner way?

**EDIT**

Here is the script snippet ..

```
# ...
broot=$(dirname "${PWD}")
i="${PWD}/list.include"
x="${PWD}/list.exclude"
o="$broot/archive.tgz"
tar -zpcf $o -T $i -X $x
# ...
```

Here is the exclusion file ..

```
/etc/php5/fpm
/etc/nginx
/etc/mysql
/home/me/websites/*log.txt
/home/me/websites/**/vendor
```

The goal is to exclude all log files located inside "websites" directory and all "vendor" directories that could be found within any sub-directories of "websites".

Comment: According to the info page for my version of GNU tar, --exclude-from will read patterns from that file, and the example is "*.o", so maybe your version of tar behaves differently? Are the exclude-file entries all one-per-line?

Comment: **Copy-paste the exact command you ran**. I took a guess in my answer, but I may be off the mark, since my crystal ball didn't find your attempts. What were you trying to do with `**`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, each path has its own line

Comment: @Gilles I will post contents as an edit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shell expands wildcards in arguments, so most applications don't need to perform any wildcard expansion. However tar's exclude list *does* support wildcards, which happen to match the wildcards supported by traditional shells. Beware that there may be slight differences; for example tar doesn't distinguish `*` and `**` like ksh, bash and zsh can. With tar, `*` can match any character including `/`, so for example `*/.svn` excludes a file called `.svn` at any level of the hierarchy. You can use `tar --no-wildcards-match-slash` in which case `*` doesn't match directory separators.

For example, excluding `/home/me/websites/*log.txt` excludes `/home/me/websites/log.txt`, `/home/me/websites/foo-log.txt` and `/home/me/websites/subdir/log.txt`. Excluding `/home/me/websites/**/vendor` excludes `/home/me/websites/one/vendor` and `/home/me/websites/one/two/vendor` but not `/home/me/websites/vendor`. With the `--no-wildcards-match-slash` option, `/home/me/websites/*log.txt` does not exclude `/home/me/websites/subdir/log.txt` and `/home/me/websites/**/vendor` does not exclude `/home/me/websites/one/two/vendor`.

`tar … --exclude='/home/www-data/sites/*include' …` excludes the files and directories under `/home/www-data/sites` whose name ends with `include`. You might get away without the quotes, but not if you write <s>`--exclude /home/www-data/sites/*include`</s> (because then the shell would expand the wildcards before `tar` can see them) or if you use a shell that signals an error on non-matching wildcards (e.g. zsh in its default — *and recommended* — configuration).

The option `--exclude-from` requires a file name. The file must contain one pattern per line. Do not confuse `--exclude` (followed by a pattern) and `--exclude-from` (followed by the name of a file containing patterns).

Comment: It would be nice if OP quoted the actual command, but the comment about "append into" made it sound as if the `--exclude-from` option were used more/less correctly.

Comment: it appears that `--wildcars-match-slash` option is default behaviour `:/` *When wildcards match slash (the default for exclusion members), …*

Comment: @Stphane Oh, right, tar is backwards, sorry. Fixed, and updated to match the question.

Comment: @gilles thank you for the update .. Maybe I only needed AGILE assitance ^^ to point out some syntax error ^^ I will review all that, revise my scripts and post results. To be continued …

Answer (score 0):

Your command was probably improperly quoted (and a quick check here works as expected).  According to the reference manual, GNU tar recognizes shell wildcards:

- [6.4 Excluding Some Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html)

  > `--exclude-from=`*file*
  >   `-X` *file*
  >   Causes tar to ignore files that match the patterns listed in *file*.
- [6.5 Wildcards Patterns and Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_50.html)